# Не устанавливаются права на директорию проекта laravel в контейнере

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`php Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/project

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add zip git libzip-dev postgresql-client postgresql-dev

## Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache zip pdo_pgsql

RUN apk add --no-cache bash

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/project
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  # NGINX - Service
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker-compose/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8143:443"
    links:
      - php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/project

  # PHP-FPM - Service
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker-compose/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/project
```

Когда захожу в контейнер, то права у всех файлов и директорий в проекте `1001`. Как правильно настроить или установить права `www-data`?